# Imacros: How to do next thing immediately without waiting load page?

Tags: timeout, loading, imacros

I have imacros code like this:

```
VERSION BUILD=8871104 RECORDER=FX
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 0
SET !TIMEOUT 0
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qg-nIAnUZwE
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXVeHWN9Xuw
TAB OPEN
TAB T=3
URL GOTO=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZPYWcAg86Q
TAB OPEN
TAB T=4
URL GOTO=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kABkuIF7zWg
```

The above code work but it is slow because it had to wait to load page before do next tab. So, there is any way to do next tab IMMEDIATELY without waiting load page ? I use timeout but it doesn't work. Thank you very much !

Comment: SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 3

Try replacing 0 with 3.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing your code in such manner:

```
...
SET blankHtml file:///D:/blank.html
TAB T=1
URL GOTO={{blankHtml}}
URL GOTO=javascript:{function<SP>setHref(){window.location.href="https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=Qg-nIAnUZwE";}var<SP>tot=window.setTimeout("setHref()",100);}
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO={{blankHtml}}
URL GOTO=javascript:{function<SP>setHref(){window.location.href="https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=BXVeHWN9Xuw";}var<SP>tot=window.setTimeout("setHref()",100);}
...
```

('file:///D:/blank.html' is a path to a blank html-file. Simply needed to run 'URL GOTO=javascript:{...'.)